# Integral of negative exponent that has interval in positive and negative

Tags: calculus, integration

I worked $$\int_{-1}^{2}\frac{4}{x^3} \, dx.$$  frankly, i didn't think much about this and simply integrating this into $\frac{-2}{x^2}$ and plug the interval like usual ( applying FTC ) and get $\frac{3}{2}$ as result, then i checked the worksheet and it's written that above function is not continuous (at zero precisely)  so that FCT is can't be applied into.

So, i wondering how solve problem like this ? since basically we always get asymptote (discontinue) when we have negative power function and inteval that pass through zero . i tried sought some reference and i found

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x} \, dx.$$

is not exist, could it be my function above is categorized as this one ?

Comment: The function is not Riemann Integrable because it's not bounded, so evaluating its "antiderivative" would make no sense.

Comment: @ClementYung 1) Unbounded functions can still have (improper) Riemann integrals. 2) The antiderivative makes perfect sense and doesn't need scare quotes... what doesn't make sense is using FTC in a situation where it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{-}}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon} \frac{4}{x^3} dx +\lim_{\eta \to 0^{+}} \int_{\eta}^{2} \frac{4}{x^3} dx$$

But $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{-}}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon} \frac{4}{x^3} dx=-2 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{-}} (\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+1)=\infty$$

The integral is divergent.